# salesforce EMP connector API version 37.0 failing with error message unsupported API version

Tags: java, salesforce, connector

I am using emp-connector for consuming salesforce straming API, I started with LogingExample from the salesforce documentation and its working file for API version 36.0, but when I try to use API Version 37.0.

I am getting following response back

> [{"channel":"/meta/handshake","error":"400::Unsupported API version.
>   Only API versions '35.0' and '36.0' are
>   supported.","successful":false}]

and when I specify API version 36.0 I code is working fine and recieving event via `PushTopic`

I know that API version 37.0 should be supported, so Not able to find out what am i doing wrong?

There is no issue with code as it works fine when I specify API version 36.0, still pasting the code here for reference

```
public class SFPoc {
public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception {
    String userName = "<someuser>";
    String password = "<pwd>";
    /*String pushTopicName = "/topic/InvoiceStatementUpdates";*/
    String pushTopicName = "/topic/Lead2";
    long replayFrom = EmpConnector.REPLAY_FROM_EARLIEST;
    String securityToken = "<securityToken>";

    BayeuxParameters custom = getBayeuxParamWithSpecifiedAPIVersion("37.0");
    BayeuxParameters params = null;
    try {
        params = login(userName, password +  securityToken, custom);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Consumer<Map<String, Object>> consumer = event -> System.out.println(String.format("Received:\n%s", event));
    EmpConnector connector = new EmpConnector(params);

    connector.start().get(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    TopicSubscription subscription = connector.subscribe(pushTopicName, replayFrom, consumer).get(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    System.out.println(String.format("Subscribed: %s", subscription));
}

private static BayeuxParameters getBayeuxParamWithSpecifiedAPIVersion(String apiVersion) {
    BayeuxParameters params = new BayeuxParameters() {

        @Override
        public String version() {
            return apiVersion;
        }

        @Override
        public String bearerToken() {
            return null;
        }

    };
    return  params;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have pushed a change to master in the emp-connector that modifies the endpoints for versions < 37.  Can you try this version and see if that fixes your issue?

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will try it in sometime and will update results here

Comment: I am still getting same error, when trying with version 37.0

Comment: One more thing, As I mentioned in question it was always working with version 36.0, isue I am facing is when I specify version 37.0

Comment: Actually it did worked after small modification in EMP code, I think you missed small part to modify the COMETD_REPLAY,  both COMETD_REPLAY & COMETD_REPLAY_OLD to points to same

Comment: can you pls check and push this changes as well, thanks